# Consuming SignalR on Flutter using ASP.NET 5 WEB API

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, flutter-dependencies, .net-5

Hello I'm a beginner on build RealTime apps, I actually have a Flutter and I'm responsible on providing API's to it and I'm using ASP.NET WEB API 5 and I want to add Realtime feature on server, I heard about SignalR that's a type of a websockets so If that's true means client (Flutter) can establish connection with my server using this library [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) ? Thanks